# disabling all command button inside the option group/ rectangle box using ms access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a userform with lots of command button inside and outside the option group/ rectangle box. What I need is to disable all the command button inside the option group/ rectangle box and retain only the cbutton outside the option group/ rectangle as enabled.

Here is my code:

> ```
> Dim ctrl As Control
> 'loop through all form controls
> For Each ctrl In Me.Frame106.Controls
>   'if control is a Command Button
>   If TypeOf ctrl Is CommandButton Then
>       'set caption to null
>       ctrl.Enabled = false
>   End If
> Next ctrl
> ```

I did some research and got the same code but the code is not working on my side. Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'frame'?

Comment: what I meant is the option group. :)

Comment: Why do you have command buttons within an option group? How did you get them in there? Option group is intended for radio buttons or checkboxes or toggle buttons. Why would you not want command buttons to have a caption? You could put text in Tag property and code test for that text and only change those that do or don't have it.

Comment: i revised my code instead of removing the caption, what i need to do is to disabling the command button in a rectangle or option group? You mean, that the option group is only intended for radio, checkboxes and toogle buttons? But, when I did my research there are some examples that the command button or textboxes are in option group.

Comment: Well, I attempted to put buttons inside option group and it fails. I would like to see what you read. A rectangle control can look like option group frame but it is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some testing, and maybe an easy way of solving this would be to place your command buttons on a separate form, instead of a group box, and then use this form as a  subform on you main form. You can make this look visually identical to a group box.

Comment: Please add related TAGS. from your question, no one can identify what actually you are asking.